# Set entire column of one dataframe as min value of column from another dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to add a new column to `df_1` which has the value of every row as the min value of the `timestamp` column fron `df_2`.

I am thinking something along the lines of the following, but this throws an error.

```
min_timestamp = df_2.select(F.min('timestamp'))

df_1 = df_1.withColumn('timestamp', F.lit(min_timestamp))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close. You just need to collect that value into the variable:

```
min_timestamp = df_2.select(F.min('timestamp')).head()[0]

df_1 = df_1.withColumn('timestamp', F.lit(min_timestamp))
```

Comment: Can you explain why `.head()` is needed?

Comment: @KOB that's because `df2.select(...)` returns a dataframe with one row and one column. You need to use `head()` to collect the only entry into a variable.